# .split("1px") into ["1px",1,"px"] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm rubbish at Regular Expressions, really!

What I'd like is to split a string containing a CSS property value into an array of `[string,value,unit]`.

For example: if I supplied the `.split()` method with `1px` it'd return `["1px",1,"px"]`. If I were to supply, similarly, `10%` it'd return `["10%",10,"%"]`.

Can this be done?

I appreciate all your help!

Update: I'd also like it to return `["1.5em",1.5,"em"]` if `1.5em` were supplied. But, if possible, still return null if supplied `yellow`. Unfortunately `/^([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)(.*)/` supplied with `yellow` would return `y,,y`!

Thanks so far guys!

Comment: Please use backticks to format code, not `<code>` tags.  Here's the complete Markdown reference: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using capturing groups:

```
var matches = "100%".match(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$/);
```

You're in luck. `match` returns an array with the full match on the first position, followed by each group.
`split` is probably wrong here, since you want to keep the full match. If you wanted to get `['100', '%']`, for example, you could have done `.split(/\b/)`.

Updated to enable fractions. Also, the use of both anchors will not match when the format isn't `[number][unit]`, so `null` is returned.

Comment: This is very nearly there, only it returns <code>["1.5em",1.5,.5,"em"]</code> and <code>["1em",1,,"em"]</code>.

Comment: @​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Jay - My bad, should have been a non-capturing group.

Comment: split(/\b/) is WRONG, it does not split "100%" into ['100', '%] unless there is a space between the two like: "100 %"

Comment: @Marco - Hello! Seems to work well for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/QftyC/ . `\b` matches the boundary between an alphanumeric (`0`) to a non-alphanumeric (`%`), so it works perfectly in this case, and should work in all flavors. It will not work well for `1.1` or `1em` though, only for `100%`.

Comment: I didn't think you wanted to split only '100%', I thought the solution should work also for something like "300px", "1em" etc.

Answer (score 10):

```
"1px".match(/(\d*\.?\d*)(.*)/)
```

yields

```
["1px", "1", "px"]
```

---

I've updated the expression to match real numbers with leading and trailing decimals.

```
var expr  = /(\d*\.?\d*)(.*)/,
    cases = [
    "1px",
    "1.px",
    "11.px",
    "11.1px",
    "11.11px",
    "1.11px",
    ".11px",
    ".1px",
    ".px" // Invalid numeric value, but still preserves unit and can be handled as seen below
];

for ( var i=0,l=cases.length; i<l; ++i ) {
    var r = cases[i].match(expr );
    console.log(r, parseFloat(r[1], 10) || 0);
}
```

Results

```
["1px", "1", "px"] 1
["1.px", "1.", "px"] 1
["11.px", "11.", "px"] 11
["11.1px", "11.1", "px"] 11.1
["11.11px", "11.11", "px"] 11.11
["1.11px", "1.11", "px"] 1.11
[".11px", ".11", "px"] 0.11
[".1px", ".1", "px"] 0.1
[".px", ".", "px"] 0
```

Comment: Also, if you want the "1" to be a number, just use `var aaa[1] = parseInt(aaa[1],10)`

Comment: `parseFloat` is actually more appropriate.

Comment: cool, how about completing expr with plus/minus sign var expr = /^([\+\-]?\d*\.?\d*)(.*)$/

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
cssProperty.match(/^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)(.*)/);
```

Comment: As both answers are the same, who do I choose to have the correct answer? Help!

Comment: @Justin, as your answer needed to be edited, and Josh's worked right out of the box, I am so sorry, but he has the points! Please forgive me!

Comment: `cssProperty.match(/^([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)(.*)/);` will also support `1.5em`

Comment: @Jay: Accept whichever one you want. In full disclosure, I edited my answer twice, once to change `split` to `match` (*you* threw me off and I realized 10 second after posting you wanted `match` :-) and again to incorporate dev-null-dweller's excellent advice.

Comment: @Jay: See the question [Who do you reward points to when more than one is right?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50486/who-do-you-reward-points-to-when-more-than-one-is-right/50488#50488)

Answer (score 1):

More complicated but will return parsed number and null for some garbage strings

```
String.prototype.unitSplit = function(parse){
    var retArr = this.toString().match(/^([\d]*\.?[\d]+)([^\d]*)$/);
    if(retArr && parse != undefined)
    {
        retArr[1] = (retArr[1].indexOf('.') >= 0)?parseFloat(retArr[1]):parseInt(retArr[1]);
    }
    return retArr;
}
/* Test cases */
"10px".unitSplit(); //["10px", "10", "px"]
"20%".unitSplit(true); //["20%", 20, "%"]
".8em".unitSplit(true); //[".8em", 0.8, "em"]
"127.0.0.1localhost".unitSplit(true); //null
```

Comment: All numbers in JavaScript are floats, so you might as well just do `retArr[1] = parseFloat(retArr[1], 10);` (you also need to explicitly include the radix).  Also, a little white space in a ternary expression never killed anyone ;) As for your expression, the range operators in your expression are not necessary when you are not negating: it could just be `(\d*\.?\d+)([^\d]*)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mySplit(str)
{
    var regex = /(\d*)([^\d]*)/;
    var t = "$1$2,$1,$2";
    return str.replace(regex,t).split(",");
}
```

Comment: This returns a string, the OP needs an array in this case. Also, `\D` is a handy replacement for `[^\d]` (there's also \W, etc)

Comment: @Kobi It would return a string except for the .split(',') I assumed would split it into an array on the ','. I didn't test it thought. oh and thanks for the \D tip! :)